# Steelseries Arctis 7 Wireless headset frequently disconnects

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

Running Ubuntu Focal 20.04.1 LTS

I've purchased a Steelseries Arctis 7 wireless headset. The connection and sound quality are perfect.

However, after 30 minutes the headset disconnects and turns itself off. The timing is very reliable, making me think it's a power-saving feature. But this happens when I'm actively using the headset, both input and output. The same setup doesn't disconnect in Windows.

I've tried the hardware reset advice; I even RMA'd a pair, got a new one, and have the exact same issue, so this definitely feels like an Ubuntu-side software issue.

Anyone run into this?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future searchers, I found a workaround. Steelseries doesn't release software for linux but they do for windows. I connected the headset to a windows machine where their software has a timeout option for powering itself off - I set this to unlimited and it seems to have changed something in the headset firmware, such that it no longers disconnects in linux.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a way to keep the power-saving feature? On windows it works well and only disconnects after 30 minutes of **inactivity** (no sound).

Comment: Actually I tried your solution and it didn't work :(, so I guess it wasn't the power saving feature. I also noticed that the timeout to shutdown isn't always the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the timeout and other settings using https://github.com/Sapd/HeadsetControl/. There is also a GUI tool to do this: https://github.com/centic9/headset-charge-indicator/.

Comment: Welcome to AU. Please could you summarise the details of that method (in case the links ever break). Thank you!